# C++ Error: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, sockets

I am attempting to create a server which accepts incoming clients, outputs a string and starts listening for incoming connections again.

I am getting this error and I don't understand what the cause is:

**Error:**

```
Error   7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: enum sf::Socket::Status __thiscall sf::TcpListener::accept(class sf::TcpSocket &)" (__imp_?accept@TcpListener@sf@@QAE?AW4Status@Socket@2@AAVTcpSocket@2@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall theServer::connect(void)" (?connect@theServer@@QAEXXZ) C:\Users\Wissam\Dropbox\Ninja Origins\Ninja Origins Official\Server\NO-Server\NO-Server\Main.obj    NO-Server
```

There are 8 errors that are similar to this.

***Code***

```
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>

class theServer {
public:
    int port = 2000;bee
    sf::TcpSocket Server;
    sf::TcpListener Listen;
    sf::IpAddress ServerIP = sf::IpAddress::getLocalAddress();

    //tmp code must be removed. (Debugging purposes)
    std::string text = "Connected";

    void connect();
    ~theServer();
};

void theServer::connect(){

    Listen.listen(port);
Listen_Again:
    if (Listen.accept(Server)){
        Server.send(text.c_str(), text.length() + 1);
        goto Listen_Again;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sfml-network library is missing. I assume you're using some Visual Studio, go to the linker settings and add it (it will be probably called smfl-network.lib or sth similar). More detailed info can be found here http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-vc.php